# DeviceCapabilities of a network printer

Tags: c++, winapi, networking, printing, gdi+

I'm trying to get list of supported page sizes of network printer using `DeviceCapabilities` and completely confused with `sPort` parameter.

```
DWORD nPapersCount = ::DeviceCapabilities(sPrinter, sPort, DC_PAPERS, nullptr, nullptr);
```

Could anyone suggest me, what should I provide in sPort for network printer and how could I reliably obtain that port?

As experiment, I have tried PC name in format "\\Share", its port "\\Share\LPT1", just "LPT1" and have no luck.

Also, I've found `EnumPorts` function, so I could obtain a list of printer ports on remote server, but I have no idea how to deal with list of ports i n case of multiple printers on server.

> ```
> typedef struct _PORT_INFO_2 {
>   LPTSTR pPortName;
>   LPTSTR pMonitorName;
>   LPTSTR pDescription;
>   DWORD  fPortType;
>   DWORD  Reserved;
> } PORT_INFO_2, *PPORT_INFO_2;
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't guess the portname, specially in case of network printers. Use [`PrintDlg`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646940(v=vs.85).aspx) to get information from currently selected printer (this can be done without showing the print dialog).

Portname is available through `hDevNames` member of [`PRINTDLG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646843(v=vs.85).aspx) structure.

[DEVNAMES structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646833(v=vs.85).aspx):

> ```
> typedef struct tagDEVNAMES {
>   WORD wDriverOffset;
>   WORD wDeviceOffset;
>   WORD wOutputOffset; //<= port name
>   WORD wDefault;
> } DEVNAMES, *LPDEVNAMES;
> ```

Unicode example:

```
PRINTDLG pdlg = { sizeof PRINTDLG };
pdlg.Flags = PD_RETURNDEFAULT;
PrintDlg(&pdlg);

LPDEVNAMES lpDev = (LPDEVNAMES)GlobalLock(pdlg.hDevNames);
std::wstring device = (LPCTSTR)lpDev + lpDev->wDeviceOffset;
std::wstring port = (LPCTSTR)lpDev + lpDev->wOutputOffset;
::GlobalUnlock(pdlg.hDevNames);

//clean up after PrintDlg, as pointed out by @RemyLebeau
GlobalFree(pdlg.hDevMode);
GlobalFree(pdlg.hDevNames);

int nPapersCount;
nPapersCount = ::DeviceCapabilities(device.c_str(), port.c_str(), DC_PAPERS, NULL, NULL);
if (nPapersCount > 0)
{
    WORD* sizeBuf = new WORD[nPapersCount];
    DeviceCapabilities(device.c_str(), port.c_str(), DC_PAPERS, (LPTSTR)sizeBuf, NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < nPapersCount; i++)
        std::wcout << sizeBuf[i] << "\n";
    delete[] sizeBuf;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to free the `hDevMode`, `hDevNames`, and `hDC` handles in the `PRINTDLG` struct after you are done using it.  Use `GlobalFree()` and `DeleteDC()` for that. Are you sure you need `PD_RETURNDC`, though? You are not using the `hDC` for anything.

Comment: @RemyLebeau there is no allocation, so there is no need for `GlobalFree`. There is no DC either. `PD_RETURNDC` was unnecessary, I removed it.

Comment: The [`PRINTDLG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646843.aspx) documentation clearly states that `hDevMode` and `hDevNames` are allocated if they are NULL on input. What it doesn't say is whether `PD_RETURNDEFAULT` changes that behavior. All it says is that they are set to handles for the system default printer. Are they allocated? Or they static and owned by the OS? The documentation does not say one way or the other. But most `PD_RETURNDEFAULT` examples I can find call `GlobalFree()` on them.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are right. I have to call `GlobalFree` otherwise there is memory leak. The documentation was not all that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Using PrintDlg is a little unwieldy, and has the disadvantage that it only lets you query the default printer (AFAIK).  The better bet is to use GetPrinter, with a requested output level of 5:

```
HANDLE h = NULL;
OpenPrinter(printerName, &h, NULL);  // printerName is a LPWSTR
if (!h) 
    return;
DWORD cbBuf=0;
GetPrinter(h, 5, NULL, 0, &cbBuf);
    // First call to GetPrinter determines an output buffer size
BYTE *buf = new BYTE[cbBuf];
if (!GetPrinter(h, 5, buf, cbBuf, &cbBuf))
    { ClosePrinter(h);  return; }
PRINTER_INFO_5 *ppi = (PRINTER_INFO_5*) buf;
LPWSTR port = ppi->pPortName;
ClosePrinter(h);
```