# PrintDlgEx fails with "Invalid Argument"

Tags: c, winapi, printing

I am Working with Win32 API and C.
I need to get supported page sizes of my system default printer.
Referring to [DeviceCapabilities of a network printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045667/devicecapabilities-of-a-network-printer) on this forum (which suggested PrintDlg), I am trying to use PrintDlgEx, with Flags=PD_RETURNDEFAULT.
My problem is, call to PrintDlgEx fails with error "E_INVALIDARG", ie, Invalid Argument.
I have written the code as a console program.
Can some one help me identify what is going wrong.

My code is pasted below

```
int main(void)
{
HWND Myhwnd =  GetConsoleWindow();
if (Myhwnd == NULL)
    printf("GetConsoleWindow Failed \n");
PRINTDLGEX pdlg;
memset(&pdlg, 0, sizeof(PRINTDLGEX));
pdlg.lStructSize = sizeof(PRINTDLGEX);
pdlg.hwndOwner = Myhwnd;
pdlg.Flags = PD_RETURNDEFAULT|| PD_NOPAGENUMS;
pdlg.nCopies = 1;
pdlg.nPropertyPages = 0;
pdlg.dwResultAction = 0;
pdlg.nStartPage = START_PAGE_GENERAL;

HRESULT result = PrintDlgEx(&pdlg);
switch (result)
  {
...  ...
  case E_INVALIDARG:
      printf("Invalid Argument\n");
  break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I noticed in PrintDlgEx documentation it says "This structure must be declared dynamically using a memory allocation function.". So I changed my program as below, but still gives same error "Invalid Argument".

```
int main(void)
{
    HWND Myhwnd =  GetConsoleWindow();
    if (Myhwnd == NULL)
        printf("GetConsoleWindow Failed \n");

    PRINTDLGEX * pdlg;
    pdlg = malloc(sizeof(PRINTDLGEX));
  memset(pdlg, 0, sizeof(PRINTDLGEX));
  pdlg->lStructSize = sizeof(PRINTDLGEX);
  pdlg->hwndOwner = Myhwnd;
  pdlg->Flags = PD_RETURNDEFAULT|| PD_NOPAGENUMS;
  pdlg->nCopies = 1;
  pdlg->nPropertyPages = 0;
  pdlg->dwResultAction = 0;
  pdlg->nStartPage = START_PAGE_GENERAL;

  HRESULT result = PrintDlgEx(pdlg);
  switch (result)
  {
...  ...
case E_INVALIDARG:
      printf("Invalid Argument\n");
      break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `PD_RETURNDEFAULT|| PD_NOPAGENUMS` uses boolean OR. You certainly want binary OR, i.e. `PD_RETURNDEFAULT | PD_NOPAGENUMS`.

Comment: Thanks,  IInspectable , and @fpiette . I made the change, and the program works (I get return code "success". And, yes, it was a silly mistake :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code with MSVC2019. As IInspectable said in a comment, the error is the use of boolean or `||` operator instead of bitwise or `|`operator.

I also checked that the call work with a statically allocated PRINTDLGEX variable or a dynamically allocated one.

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    HWND Myhwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    if (Myhwnd == NULL)
        printf("GetConsoleWindow Failed \n");

    PRINTDLGEX pdlg;
    memset(&pdlg, 0, sizeof(PRINTDLGEX));
    pdlg.lStructSize = sizeof(PRINTDLGEX);
    pdlg.hwndOwner = Myhwnd;
    pdlg.Flags = PD_RETURNDEFAULT | PD_NOPAGENUMS;
    pdlg.nCopies = 1;
    pdlg.nPropertyPages = 0;
    pdlg.dwResultAction = 0;
    pdlg.nStartPage = START_PAGE_GENERAL;

    HRESULT result = PrintDlgEx(&pdlg);
    switch (result)
    {
    case S_OK:
        printf("Success\n");
        break;
    case E_INVALIDARG:
        printf("Invalid Argument\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("Error %d\n", result);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```